# How to force excel to use another office application's (word) "application" attributes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm currently trying to get the character position of the paragraph/line right after a table of contents in a word document using VBA within excel. The issue is that the code which I use to get that character position only works within word because I'm using the `Application` keyword within Excel and not within Word. Is there a way to get that position in excel using VBA?

As I've said, I've already found a way to get the character position in word:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Dim tocEnd As Long
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim inputPath As String

inputPath = "somepath"

Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(inputPath)

If doc.TablesOfContents.Count = 1 Then tocEnd = doc.TablesOfContents.Application.Selection.Range.End Else tocEnd = 0

Debug.Print doc.TablesOfContents.Application.Selection.End

End Sub
```

Within excel, I use:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim inputDoc As String

inputDoc = "someinput"

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(inputDoc)

Debug.Print doc.TablesOfContents.Application.Selection.End

tocEnd = doc.TablesOfContents.Application.Selection.End

doc.Close False

End Sub
```

Within excel, my tocEnd variable becomes equal to 0. In word, it's the right character position.

Code above not working, here's a workaround. I just don't know how to assign the fld.select range to a range variable, say `rng`.

```
Sub test()

Dim fld As Field
Dim rng As Range

For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields

    If fld.Type = wdFieldTOC Or fld.Type = wdFieldTOCEntry Or fld.Type = wdFieldHyperlink Then
        fld.Select
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application` isn't a keyword (keywords get a bright blue syntax highlighting), it's a global object - *the* root object at the top of the host application's object model. That said I've no idea what "*the code which I use to get that character position only works within word because I'm using the Application keyword within Excel and not within Word*" means. Where are you `Set`ting the `objWord` reference? Without `Set objWord = New Word.Application`, the `Set doc = objWord.Application.Documents.Open(...)` instruction should blow up with error 91.

Comment: `ActiveDocument` will be `Nothing` if this code is executed hosted in Excel. You need to `Set doc = objWord.ActiveDocument` *after* setting the `objWord` reference.

Comment: It means that my tocEnd variable becomes equal to 0 after I run the code above, in addition to having instantiated my word application object with this code `Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")`. I don't get any errors and I do not have a `On error resume next` line ignoring errors.

Comment: It's not because of Option Explicit, added it in the code. As I said, there is no error. I simply cannot get to use word's "global object" as you've stated to find the character position after the table of contents

Comment: Thanks for editing, it's clearer now... although it's still not making sense how `Set doc = objWord.Documents...` can work with `objWord` never being assigned anything in the top snippet)... Note that `doc.Application` is the very same `Application` object as `doc.TablesOfContents.Application` ...there's only one `Application.Selection` AFAIK; the selection doesn't belong to `TablesOfContents`, it belongs to `[Word.]Application`/`objWord`. Lastly, you aren't assigning `tocEnd` (it's not in the Excel/bottom snippet?), so... it's `0`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the insufficient code (forgot to assign tocEnd) but it's basically what I get from `Debug.Print`.

Comment: Is there a reason you try to use exactly the same code within Word as within Excel? On the Excel side, I'd use `tocEnd = objWord.Selection.End`. But even in the Word version I'd simply use `Application.Selection.End`. If I absolutely had to get the `Application` object from the document I'd use `Document.Parent.Selection`.

Comment: So I just realized that the application isn't actually working. Not only that, `doc.tablesofcontents` is not always a non-zero value, though you do have a tables of contents, especially when it is a manual one. As a workaround, I'm looping through fields and using if statements to get actual toc fields. Now the issue is that I don't know how to use a range object other than `Selection`. See edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is not to do with using another application's object model.

All that your code is picking up is the location of the beginning and end of the Selection in the Word application. But for example, all that the following line does:

```
doc.TablesOfContents.Application.Selection.End
```

is to use the Application member of the TablesOfContents object to return a reference to the Word Application. It doesn't tell word to select anything, so the code will just pick up the current Selection (whatever it is) and return the value of its End property. You would get the same result using, e.g.

```
objWord.Selection.End
```

(bearing in mind Mathieu Guidon's observation that your first code sample does not actually make sense, which suggests that your test code is currently doing something else, e.g. perhaps returning the location of the Selection in a document that is already open).

Further, when you open a document in code, via the object model, the Selection would be at the beginning of the document, so you wouldn't get the result you wanted that way either.

What you really need to do is create the Word app (or use GetObject to get an existing instance), open the document if it isn't open, then look at

```
doc.TablesOfContents.Count
```

If it's 0, there are no TOCs

If it's >0, then the question is "what location are you really trying to return?"

If it's the end of the first ToC, you would need something like

```
tocEnd = doc.TablesOfContents(1).Range.End
```

If it's the end of the last ToC, you would need something like

```
tocEnd = doc.TablesOfContents(doc.TablesOfContents.Count).Range.End
```

(I am currently a "guest" poster here so do not think I can follow this up!)

In general the other things you need to do when accessing another program's object model are:
 a. always qualify the objects you use unambiguously. Otherwise, for example, VBA may confuse a Word Range and an Excel Range
 b. If you don't make a reference to the relevant object model via Tools->References (which people typically avoid doing when using Late Binding as you are doing, you can't use the named constants from that model. (You don't in your sample code, but I mention it because it's one of the most common problems in this area).